# why does this run() command run without anything calling it?

Tags: python, multithreading, class, pynput

so i was messing around with python when i came across this autoclicker code on the internet

```
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode


delay = 0.001
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='s')
exit_key = KeyCode(char='e')


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)


mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()


def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == exit_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

after a bit of research i understand most of it but im still confused about one thing,
why does the run() command in the class work automatically even when nothing is calling it? there isnt a single other "run" in this code

thanks in advance

Comment: Your code *does* call ‘start()’ which itself calls ‘run()’

Comment: @quamrana, That's misleading. The `start()` method does not _call_ the `run()` method. The `start()` method creates a new native thread, and _something in the new thread_ calls the `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical "threading" pattern. You first subclass "Thread" and override the `run()` method.

After that you crate an instance of that class which you see here:

```
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()
```

The "start" method launches the thread which uses the "run" function. So the line that effectively "makes the `run()` method run" is `click_thread.start()`.

You can find more details in the docs of [threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects)